# My mobile nav menu is not disappearing when anchor links are clicked

Tags: javascript, menu

We have a single page scrolling website, and are using anchor links in the navigation menu to scroll throughout the page. On the mobile menu after you click the link it scrolls but the menu stays open, despite our attempts to code it otherwise. My first time using the platform, apologies in advanced if I am not giving the right information! I have looked at similarly titled posts but cant seem to find the similarities between the situations. Thanks!

`jQuery(document).ready(function($){ // $(document).on('click','nav li.menu-item-has-children > a',function(e){ e.preventDefault(); var open = $(this).parent('li').hasClass('show'); if(open){ //close it $(this).parent('li').removeClass('show'); $(this).attr('aria-expanded', 'false'); }else{ //check for sub menu click var subClick = $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').hasClass('sub-menu'); if(!subClick){ $('li.menu-item-has-children').removeClass('show'); } // open it $(this).parent('li').addClass('show'); $(this).attr('aria-expanded', 'true'); } return false; }); // $("#mobile-icon").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); console.log('clicked'); var open = $(this).hasClass('is-open'); if(open){ $(this).removeClass('is-open'); $('nav#mobile').removeClass('is-open'); }else{ $(this).addClass('is-open'); $('nav#mobile').addClass('is-open'); } }); });`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //
    $(document).on('click','nav li.menu-item-has-children > a',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var open = $(this).parent('li').hasClass('show');
        if(open){
            //close it
            $(this).parent('li').removeClass('show');
            $(this).attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
        }else{
            //check for sub menu click
            var subClick = $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').hasClass('sub-menu');
            if(!subClick){
                $('li.menu-item-has-children').removeClass('show');
            }
            // open it
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('show');
            $(this).attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
        }
        return false;
    });
    //
    $("#mobile-icon").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('clicked');
        var open = $(this).hasClass('is-open');
        if(open){
            $(this).removeClass('is-open');
            $('nav#mobile').removeClass('is-open');
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('is-open');
            $('nav#mobile').addClass('is-open');
        }
    });
});
```